# How to correctly handle dependencies of injected dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll-injection

I am currently try to extend a video game with dll injection. While I have no problem injecting my dll, I am unsure how I should handle dependencies of my dll. First I linked them statically. But I read many times it would be better to link them dynamically.

The problem with this is that I don't want to put the dlls into the game folder. But it looks like windows is only looking for the other dlls in the game.exe folder instead of in the folder where my injected dll is.

My guess to solve the problem was to also inject the dependencies before I inject my own dll into the game process with `LoadLibraryW`. While this seems to work I am unsure if this will work correctly under all circumstances or should I stick with static linking to avoid all that hacky stuff?

Comment: ***The problem with this is that I don't want to put the dlls into the game folder. But it looks like windows is only looking for the other dlls in the game.exe folder instead of in the folder where my injected dll is.*** They either have to be in the same folder as the executable or in one of the folders listed in the windows `PATH` environment variable. This is the same search rules for any native dll.

Comment: More info about search rules here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: I think you should just link all your dependencies statically into one dll.